# Adding tooltip to each tile in a kendo stacked bar chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart, kendo-react-ui

I have created a stacked bar chart using Kendo UI. I want to show tooltip for each tile in stacked bar chart and use another array for this purpose which contains the values to be shown as tooltip.

**For ex:** When I hover over, USA for year 2000, tooltip should show, NYC: 60% & SFO: 40% (as shown in image).

Here is a [fiddle](https://dojo.telerik.com/OfeMiHUb/2).

This is what I am trying to achieve (in this case showing tooltip for year 2000 for USA):
[image]

Problem is when I use `series click` or `series hover events`, I am not able to identify tile (inside the stacked bar chart) which is making it harder to show tooltip.

**This is the code:**

- html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

  ```
     <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  ```

  ```
       var CityData = [{country: "USA", children:[{"NYC": ["60%", "70%", "80%"]}, {"SFO": ["40%", "30%", "20%"]}]},

                       {country: "Mexico", children:[{"Mexico City": ["80%", "80%", "80%"]}, {"Cancun": ["20%", "20%", "20%"]}]},


                          {country: "Canada", children:[{"Toronto": ["50%", "60%", "60%"]}, {"Vancouver": ["50%",
  ```

  "40%", "40%"]}]}

  ```
                           ];

         function createChart() {


             $("#chart").kendoChart({
                 title: {
                     text: "City data"
                 },
                 legend: {
                     visible: false
                 },
                 seriesDefaults: {
                     type: "column",
                     stack: {
                         type: "100%"
                     }
                 },
                 series: [{
                     name: "USA",
                     stack: {
                         group: "Country"
                     },
                     data: [854622, 925844, 984930]
                 }, {
                     name: "Canada",
                     stack: {
                         group: "Country"
                     },
                     data: [490550, 555695, 627763]
                 }, {
                     name: "Mexico",
                     stack: {
                         group: "Country"
                     },
                     data: [379788, 411217, 447201]
                 }

                  ],
                 seriesColors: ["yellow", "green", "red"],
                 valueAxis: {
                     line: {
                         visible: false
                     }
                 },
                 categoryAxis: {
                     categories: [2000, 2005, 2010],
                     majorGridLines: {
                         visible: false
                     }
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                     visible: true,
                     template: "#= series.stack.group #, city #= series.name #"
                 }
             });
         }

         $(document).ready(createChart);
         $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
     </script>
  ```

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Joel: Each bar in this case has 3 tile. One for USA, one for Mexico & one for Canada. When I hover over yellow tile (for USA), I only want to show tooltip for USA which should show cities under USA with percentage values. I do not want to show data for other countries.

Comment: Yeah, shared was still active. https://dojo.telerik.com/OfeMiHUb/10 sorry dude, i dedicated too much time to this problem. Good luck!

Comment: @Joel: I am not sure whether I should thank you more for the effort or the answer. Great stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `tooltip: { shared: true }` and it will work, I included other customizable properties of `tooltip` below also.

Working demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/OfeMiHUb/4

Snippet:

```
 tooltip: {
             shared: true,
             visible: true,
             background: "#000",
             template: "#= series.stack.group #, city #= series.name #"
          }
```

or you can try this if you want another template of your tooltip: https://dojo.telerik.com/OfeMiHUb/3

## UPDATE:

What changed?:

```
tooltip: { 
     template: `USA- #= cityData[0]
                            .children
                                 .map(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0]) #`
    }
```

OP clarified further what he wanted, as *per* new information, please see new working example: https://dojo.telerik.com/OfeMiHUb/9

You can retrieve your city-data through indexing the keys of the children-object like this: `cityData[0].children.map(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0])`

Possible additions:

- If you want the series.name to be dynamically added to the tooltip, instead of explicitly typing it in. You can use: `series.name`.

Like this:

```
tooltip: { 
   template: `#= series.name # - #=
   cityData[0]
       .children
           .map(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0]) #`}
```

Change the ArrayIndex of `cityData[index]` to select a nations cities.

i.e.

```
0: USA
1: Canada 
2: Mexico
```

## UPDATE 2:

After reading through what you wrote (3000x) + looking at the image, I am interpreting that u also want the percentage showing (even tho it seems like in the clarifying comment below that u dont?). 
Anyhow:

```
        series: [{
            name: "USA",
            stack: {
                group: "Country"
            },
            tooltip: {template: `#= series.name # - #=
            cityData[0]
                .children
                    .map(itm => '[' + Object.keys(itm)[0] + ']' + ' : ' + Object.values(itm)[0][0]) #`},
            data: [854622, 925844, 984930]
        }, {
            name: "Canada",
            stack: {
                group: "Country"
            },
            tooltip: {template: `#= series.name # - #=
            cityData[1]
                .children
                    .map(itm => '[' + Object.keys(itm)[0] + ']' + ' : ' + Object.values(itm)[0][0]) #`},
            data: [490550, 555695, 627763]
        }, {
            name: "Mexico",
            stack: {
                group: "Country"
            },
                            tooltip: {template: `#= series.name # - #=
            cityData[2]
                .children
                    .map(itm => '[' + Object.keys(itm)[0] + ']' + ' : ' + Object.values(itm)[0][0]) #`},
            data:[379788, 411217, 447201]
        }

         ],
```

Almost got the percentage / series working.

Right now I'm struggling with extracting the series-index in this selector: `Object.values(itm)[0][SERIES_INDEX_SHOULD_BE_HERE]`

## TO BE CONTINUED...

Comment: Thank you for quick help. But I am not looking to show tooltip for all the countries with cities. What I want to do it when user hover over USA tile, I just want to show tooltip for USA and its cities. When I hover over, Canada, I want to show tooltip for cities from Canada for that specific year.

Comment: Oh i see, sorry. Ill send solution tomorrow when i get back to work

Comment: @OpenStack i have taken a closer look at it now, I know how to solve it, but dude, your data-structure is ducked up for CityData. Like, why did u think this was a good idea? xd. Can I change it? Then it’s ez pz. will post solution tomorrow propbably,

Comment: Thank you for actively looking into this. Feel free to change the data-structure.